# how image uploading in couchdb?

Tags: couchdb

I am planning to create one project and I am planning to use CouchDb to store my data. I have data as well as attachments in form of images. So I want to know that how image store In couch. It will give me URL in response or it will store binary data.?

Answer (score 2):

You can store image in CouchDB as attachment to document. Afterwards, you can access the attachment by id specified in document containing it.

[More on how CouchDB handles attachments](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.2.0/api/document/attachments.html)

Comment: Ruservljan Is it async call because I have to store data as well? If I want something like I am sending user object and there is also profile pic of it, Then is there any way that my user object saved and image will upload at async and Couch db maitain relations between user object and image?

Comment: If I have understood you correctly, it depends on your HTTP library that you use to access CouchDB, if it supports async (event driven) calls, then yes, if no than pick one that does.

Comment: That link is broken, making this answer useless.

Comment: The link for CouchDB used in this answer has moved to https://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/api/document/attachments.html.